# Gantt chart with arrows between the tasks

Tags: r, gantt-chart

I have a Gant chart and I need to add arrows to highlight the links between the tasks. Despite some researches, I don't know how to do that and even if it's possible.

I use the `DiagrammeR` package. I also watched the `timevis` package but I don't think that he can do that (and I like the fact that you can use a data frame to store the information in the `DiagrammeR` package).

An alternative is a sequence diagram but I need to display time-related informations (length of the tasks, timeline, etc.).

Here is an example. Suppose that I want to link the « collect » task with the « import » task with an arrow (from the first to the second).

```
library(DiagrammeR)

mermaid("
gantt
dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
title Data analysis process

section My tasks
Collect   :done,    2018-01-01, 2018-01-31
Import    :active,  2018-02-01, 2018-02-28
Clean     :active,  2018-03-01, 2018-03-31
Analyze 1 :active,  2018-04-01, 2018-04-30
Analyze 2 :active,  2018-04-01, 2018-04-30
Model     :active,  2018-05-01, 2018-05-31
")
```